# get invalid exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
  Source=kn diary
  StackTrace:
       at kn_diary.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create_*Instance*_[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
       at kn_diary.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Form1()
       at kn_diary.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in C:\Users\Pak\Desktop\project\kn diary\kn diary\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at kn_diary.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.BadImageFormatException
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
       Source=AxInterop.WMPLib
       FileName=Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
       FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Pak-PC\Pak
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Pak/Desktop/project/kn diary/kn diary/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

## Calling assembly : AxInterop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Pak\Desktop\project\kn diary\kn diary\bin\Debug\kn diary.vshost.exe.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Pak/Desktop/project/kn diary/kn diary/bin/Debug/Interop.WMPLib.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

```
   StackTrace:
        at AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.AttachInterfaces()
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
        at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
        at kn_diary.Form1.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\Pak\Desktop\project\kn diary\kn diary\Form1.designer.vb:line 91
        at kn_diary.Form1..ctor()
   InnerException:
```

Comment: sorry for posting like this. Actually i am new on stackover flow.

Comment: The problem is that i have converted the code from VS 2008 to VS 2010, some forms of VB.net are working but when i try to load one form that is mainform, the VS throw this invalid operation expection. Please help me in this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication of failure to load one of the reference assemblies in the chain of references, in this case, an indirect reference.  I normally check the fusion log to find out exactly what assembly is failing to load and often why.

Can you check the fusion log and paste the log here in case if you do not already spot the culprit there?  You can lunch logger by running "fuslogvw.exe" from VS command prompt.  (this link has more detail on how to use the fusion log viewer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.80).aspx)